# streamlit markdown css file is not working

Tags: css-selectors, streamlit

I use a separate style.css for my streamlit python file.
Below it's the code for my main streamlit script, which specifies the style.css I used.

```
with open('style.css') as f:
  st.markdown(f'<style>{f.read()}</style>', unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Here is the code for my style.css

```
div.css-z5fcl1.egzxvld4 {
  border: 1px solid #5f9ea0;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 70px;
  color: #3a668;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
}
```

It changed the border, padding, and color. However, the font-weight is not working.
How to fix this?

[image: font-weight didn't change pic]
Many thanks in advance